Регулярный запуск скрипта в Сolab c помощью Cloud Scheduler
Написала код на Python в Google Colab для выгрузки данных в Google Sheets. Необходимо запускать его каждый день в определенное время. Можно ли настроить это с помощью Cloud Scheduler?
